# Is there a tool for drawing a "data structure diagram"?

Tags: diagram, graphviz

What kind of graph types do these images belong to? Data structure diagram, maybe?

[image: screenshot from given example]

[image: screenshot from given example]

[image: screenshot from given example]

And how to draw it? Any tools for this purpose? I try to use a table with Graphviz dot, but when with a long text, the cell's width becomes a problem.

[image: screenshot from given example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know to use graphviz, but you are welcome to try LaTeX and one of its packages aka. [bytefield](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bytefield), as is answered [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464753/what-are-the-ways-to-create-draw-data-structures-for-latex).